# Error durante la compilación, alguien conoce el motivo o la solución.?

Tags: c#

Buenas. Tengo un programa decompilado con justdecompiler hecho en .net. Pero al compilar me salen algunos errores típicos que me gustaría saber alguna solucion o el motivo mismamente.
Comparto con vosotros los errores:

Los archivos autooffers.designer.cs son el mismo es donde me surge el conflicto de duplicado.

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Error       The item "Auto.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter.  AutoOffers
```

Otro error muy común:

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Mensaje     Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.         0
```

Supongo que tendre que recomponer de nuevo formularios, llamadas, etc. Si sabeis decirme porque aparecen estos errores pues me resultaría muy util.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo donde se genera estos errores ? con solo el mensaje no creo que podamos aportar mucho a una solucion

Comment: el primer error que tengo es error de duplicado porque tengo dos archivos .cs y me pone lo siguiente:                                                        The item "Auto.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter. Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter. AutoOffers

Comment: Voy a subir una captura señalando el elemento duplicado

Comment: te subi una captura sobre el archivo conflictivo

Comment: si es obvio pero como lo soluciono

Comment: el primero no lo solucione

Comment: Ok Omar, revisa mi respuesta espero te pueda ayudar.

Comment: no pude renombrar usan el mismo fichero pero no se como indicarle a visual studio. gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ya solucione el duplicado

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba el nombre del archivo que da error

abre el archivo .csproj que está en el directorio del proyecto como archivo de texto.

busca dentro de este archivo (.csproj) el nombre del archivo que da error.

deberías encontrar algo como:

`<Compile Include="dupicado.cs">
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
      <DependentUpon>Duplicate.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="dupicado.cs">
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
      <DependentUpon>Duplicate.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>`

Elimina un conjunto de "compile", la idea es que no hayan dupicados.

Guarda los cambios.

Vuelve a cargar el proyecto, esto debería bastar.

Comment: si es correcto muchas gracias el problema del duplicado lo solucione siguen otros pero gracias a ti lo solucione este problema mil gracias

Comment: @OmarAlami Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, considera aceptarla haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la respuesta (ambos se benefician). Más información en: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

El primer error lo puedes resolver renombrando `AutoOffers.Designer.cs` de `AutoOffers.EN.resx` o de `AutoOffers.NL.resx` ya que esta duplicada.

En cuanto al error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Estas accediendo a la propiedad de un objeto pero no ha sido instanciado:

Por ejemplo, tratas de acceder a la propiedad "Dato" pero no has instanciado la clase:

```
ClaseAlgo miClase;
miClase.getDato();
```

lo correcto sería:

```
ClaseAlgo miClase = new ClaseAlgo();
miClase.getDato();
```

Comment: no puedo renombrarlo

Comment: si ya solucione el duplicado

Comment: el segundo error te indica una clase? si es así agregala. :)

Comment: tengo un problema muy común si lees el otro artículo a lo mejor conoces el problema es que la clase EN. y NL. en los formularios no las reconoce. Esta solución me vale ?